# CSS3 transform multiple divs based on attribute they have

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, transform

I'm trying to write some JS that will allow HTML such as this:

```
     <div class="box" data-vert-speed="7">ContentDiv1</div>
     <div class="box" data-hori-speed="10">ContentDiv2</div>
     <div class="box" data-rota-speed="5">ContentDiv3</div>
     <div class="box" data-vert-speed="2.4">ContentDiv4</div>
     <div class="box" data-hori-speed="1.3">ContentDiv5</div>
     <div class="box" data-rota-speed="2.3">ContentDiv6</div>
```

to perform a CSS transform on each div on page scroll (the rate of which dictated by the attribute value.

where "vert" "hori" and "rota", are the CSS transforms vertical, horizontal and a rotation respectively.

The JS I have works for one of these types but I can't get it to detect all three types of attributes and execute them.

```
     $.fn.moveItrota = function(){
      var $windowr = $(window);
      var instancesr = [];

      $(this).each(function(){
        instancesr.push(new moveItItemrota($(this)));
      });

      window.onscroll = function(){
        var scrollTopr = $windowr.scrollTop();
        instancesr.forEach(function(instr){
          instr.updater(scrollTopr);
        });
      }
    }

    $.fn.moveItvert = function(){
      var $windowv = $(window);
      var instancesv = [];

      $(this).each(function(){
        instancesv.push(new moveItItemvert($(this)));
      });

      window.onscroll = function(){
        var scrollTopv = $windowv.scrollTop();
        instancesv.forEach(function(instv){
          instv.updatev(scrollTopv);
        });
      }
    }

    $.fn.moveIthori = function(){
      var $windowh = $(window);
      var instancesh = [];

      $(this).each(function(){
        instancesh.push(new moveItItemhori($(this)));
      });

      window.onscroll = function(){
        var scrollToph = $windowh.scrollTop();
        instancesr.forEach(function(insth){
          insth.updateh(scrollToph);
        });
      }
    }



    //Rotation Scrolling ------------------------------------------------

    if ($('.box').attr('data-rota-speed')){
     console.log("found a rota");   
    var moveItItemrota = function(elr){
      this.elr = $(elr);
      this.speedr = parseInt(this.elr.attr('data-rota-speed'));
      console.log(this.speedr);
    };

    moveItItemrota.prototyper.updater = function(scrollTopr){
      var posr = scrollTopr / this.speedr;
      this.elr.css('transform', 'rotate(' + -posr + 'deg)');
    };

    $(function(){
      $('[data-rota-speed]').moveItrota();
    });

    };

    //Horizontal Scrolling ------------------------------------------------

    if ($('.box').attr('data-hori-speed')){
    console.log("found a hori");
    var moveItItemhori = function(elh){
      this.elh = $(elh);
      this.speedh = parseInt(this.elh.attr('data-hori-speed'));
      console.log(this.speedh);
    };

    moveItItemhori.prototypeh.updateh = function(scrollToph){
      var posh = scrollToph / this.speedh;
      this.elh.css('transform', 'translateX(' + -posh + 'px)'); 
    };

    $(function(){
      $('[data-hori-speed]').moveIthori();
    });

    };

    //Vertical Scrolling ------------------------------------------------
    if ($('.box').attr('data-vert-speed')){
    console.log("found a vert");

    var moveItItemvert = function(elv){
      this.elv = $(elv);
      this.speedv = parseInt(this.elv.attr('data-vert-speed'));
      console.log(this.speedv);
    };

    moveItItemvert.prototype.updatev = function(scrollTopv){
      var posv = scrollTopv / this.speedv;
      this.elv.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -posv + 'px)');
    };

    $(function(){
      $('[data-vert-speed]').moveItvert();
    });

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can tell from your code is that you have 2 data points on the same attribute, I would suggest separate them (if possible). From your code, I assume every element has a single movement type and the movement speed. If there is more than one, this may require a bit of tweaking. If my assumption is correct, you could do something like:

```
<div class="box" data-movement="vertical" data-speed="7">ContentDiv1</div>
<div class="box" data-movement="horizontal" data-speed="10">ContentDiv2</div>
<div class="box" data-movement="rotation" data-speed="5">ContentDiv3</div>
<div class="box" data-movement="vertical" data-speed="2.4">ContentDiv4</div>
<div class="box" data-movement="horizontal" data-speed="1.3">ContentDiv5</div>
<div class="box" data-movement="rotation" data-speed="2.3">ContentDiv6</div>
```

Then on js, get the items and apply the css

```
var boxItems = $(".box");
$.map(boxItems, function(item, i) {
   var movement = $(item).data("movement");
   var speed = $(item).data("speed");
   switch(movement) {
      case "horizontal": {
         // move horizontally (not sure if this is done with transforms)
         break;
      }
      case "vertical": {
         // move vertically (not sure if this is done with transforms)
         break;
      }
      case "rotation": {
         // rotate (not sure if this is done with transforms)
         break;
      }
   }
});
```

I did not write the movement code since not sure if you are using `css` transform ... but just in case, here is a link that describes how to apply this.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transform.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi David, many thanks for your answer. I've still not quite got it to work. I would like to do the transforms via CSS as shown in my original question. I'm not sure how to get those into your code, I've tried a few different ways but nothing is happening. In fact i'm getting an error saying "moveItItemvert is not defined".